# Are python 3.6.9 and python 3.7.4 compatible?

Tags: python

My friend and I are working on a project. We both setup our vitualenvs but I use python 3.6.9 while my friend is using python 3.7.4. Will this cause issues during development?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the same versions when possible. Why not install Python 3.7.4 yourself (or, better yet, both of you can install the latest release)? Tools like `pyenv` can make this pretty trivial.

Comment: Code written to 3.6.9 should work fine in 3.7.4, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this cause issues during development?

It depends. If you agree to stick to the features that are available in 3.6 it will probably be fine.

But it means for example you can't use `dataclasses`, and you'd have to be careful when using `asyncio`.

I would advise you *both* to use the Python documentation for 3.6. That would lessen the chance of introducing an incompatible feature.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to be bit cautious and refer to

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0387/